# Standard TFlite object detection model not working in MLKit

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

If I use the [Pre-Trained TFLite Object detection model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview) in MLKit, I get the following error:

> ```
>  CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run: 
>     Calculator::Open() for node "BoxClassifierCalculator" failed: #vk Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0: got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1).
> ```

Any Idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

ML Kit does not currently support custom object detection model yet. ML Kit currently only allows developers to use custom image classification models.  All TFLite models that are compatible with ML Kit are listed here:

https://tfhub.dev/ml-kit/collections/image-classification/1

If you want to do object detection, you can try out ML Kit's Object Detection API: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection

If you want to use a custom object detection model, you can try TFLite task library:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/overview.

Comment: How near in the future will custom tflite model be supported for mlkit object detection api?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'm using https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android that it's suppose to support custom models. Any ideas?

Comment: It supports compatible custom classification models listed here: https://tfhub.dev/ml-kit/collections/image-classification/1, but not custom detection models, or other arbitrary custom models.

Comment: There is no near-term plan for supporting custom detection model.

Comment: Then what this custom model detection do? https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android

Comment: ML Kit's Object Detection involves two kinds of models: models for object detection and models for image classification.  ML Kit supports customization for the latter (with a custom image classification model), but not yet the former (with a custom object detection model).

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, and there is a tiny little note in blue at this page https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#model_compatibility_requirements that actually tells about this lack of compability. Amazing

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I found out through this post here on SO, I went on to look for other options.
And the tutorial posted here: [Tensor Flow Lite OBJ detection](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/tflite-object-detection-android#0) did the trick just nicely.

First of all added the

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.2.0'
```

To build.gradle, and this simple code worked like a charm. Obviously I have to make some changes to reflect my specific needs, but it's detecting without errors.

```
val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
val options = ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.builder()
    .setMaxResults(5)
    .setScoreThreshold(0.5f)
    .build()
val detector = ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(
    this, // the application context
    "model.tflite", // must be same as the filename in assets folder
    options
)
```

A more in depth explanation is given in that link, too much to be thrown here.
Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You can now create MLKit Custom Models with Google's Vertex AI/AutoML Cloud service and it works well with the CameraX API using an `ImageAnalysis Analyzer`. Follow the guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/image-recognition-automl) to make and train the TFLite model with your own images via browser (or use the Google Cloud CLI if you have many to upload). After that, [this guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android) walks you through pretty much everything you need to add the model to your project, and how detect and label objects with MLKit.