# Issue in creating Tflite model populated with metadata (for object detection)

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, metadata, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run a tflite model on Android for object detection. For the same,

1. I have successfully trained the model with my sets of images as follows:

(a) Training:

```
!python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/My\ Drive/Detecto\ Tutorial/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
--model_dir=training/
```

(modifying the config file to point to where my specific TFrecords are mentioned)

(b) Export inference graph

```
!python /content/drive/'My Drive'/'Detecto Tutorial'/models/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
--input_type=image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/My\ Drive/Detecto\ Tutorial/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
--output_directory={output_directory} \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix={last_model_path}
```

(c) Create tflite ready graph

```
!python /content/drive/'My Drive'/'Detecto Tutorial'/models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/My\ Drive/Detecto\ Tutorial/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
  --output_directory={output_directory} \
  --trained_checkpoint_prefix={last_model_path} \
  --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

2. I have created a tflite model using tflite_convert from the graph file as follows

   !tflite_convert 
   --graph_def_file=/content/drive/My\ Drive/Detecto\ Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/tflite_graph.pb 
   --output_file=/content/drive/My\ Drive/Detecto\ Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/detect3.tflite 
   --output_format=TFLITE 
   --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 
   --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor 
   --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  
   --inference_type=FLOAT  
   --allow_custom_ops

The above tflite model is validated independently and works fine (outside of Android).

There is a requirement now to populate the tflite model with metadata so that it can be processed in the sample Android code provided as per link below (as I am getting an error otherwise: not a valid Zip file and does not have associated files when run on Android studio).

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/README.md

The sample .TFlite provided as part of the same link is populated with metadata and works fine.

When I try to use the following link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#deep_dive_into_the_image_classification_example

```
populator = _metadata.MetadataPopulator.with_model_file('/content/drive/My Drive/Detecto Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/detect3.tflite')
populator.load_metadata_buffer(metadata_buf)
populator.load_associated_files(['/content/drive/My Drive/Detecto Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/labelmap.txt'])
populator.populate()
```

to add metadata (rest of the code is practically the same with some changes of meta description to Object detection instead of Image classification and specifying the location of labelmap.txt), it gives the following error:

```
<ipython-input-6-173fc798ea6e> in <module>()
  1 populator = _metadata.MetadataPopulator.with_model_file('/content/drive/My Drive/Detecto Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/detect3.tflite')
  ----> 2 populator.load_metadata_buffer(metadata_buf)
        3 populator.load_associated_files(['/content/drive/My Drive/Detecto Tutorial/models/research/fine_tuned_model/labelmap.txt'])
        4 populator.populate()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/metadata.py in _validate_metadata(self, metadata_buf)
    540           "The number of output tensors ({0}) should match the number of "
    541           "output tensor metadata ({1})".format(num_output_tensors,
--> 542                                                 num_output_meta))
    543 
    544 

ValueError: The number of output tensors (4) should match the number of output tensor metadata (1)
```

The 4 output tensors are the ones mentioned in the output_arrays in step 2 (someone may correct me there). I am not sure how to update output tensor metadata accordingly.

Can anyone who has recently used object detection using custom model (and then apply on Android) help? Or help understand how to update tensor metadata to 4 instead of 1.

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No @Igor, still waiting for a miracle!

Comment: Thanks @[ASMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14352729/asms), check Lu Wang's answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update on Jun 10, 2021:**

See the [latest tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata_writer_tutorial) about Metadata Writer Library on tensorflow.org.

**Update**:

The [Metadata Writer library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/tree/master/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata_writers) has been released. It currently supports image classifier and object detector, and more supported tasks are on the way.

Here is an example to write metadata for an object detector model:

1. Install the TFLite Support nightly Pypi package:

```
pip install tflite_support_nightly
```

2. Write metadata to the model using the following script:

```
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import object_detector
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils
from tflite_support import metadata

ObjectDetectorWriter = object_detector.MetadataWriter
_MODEL_PATH = "ssd_mobilenet_v1_1_default_1.tflite"
_LABEL_FILE = "labelmap.txt"
_SAVE_TO_PATH = "ssd_mobilenet_v1_1_default_1_metadata.tflite"

writer = ObjectDetectorWriter.create_for_inference(
    writer_utils.load_file(_MODEL_PATH), [127.5], [127.5], [_LABEL_FILE])
writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), _SAVE_TO_PATH)

# Verify the populated metadata and associated files.
displayer = metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(_SAVE_TO_PATH)
print("Metadata populated:")
print(displayer.get_metadata_json())
print("Associated file(s) populated:")
print(displayer.get_packed_associated_file_list())
```

---------- Previous answer that writes metadata manually --------

Here is a code snippet you can use to populate metadata for object detection models, which is compatible with the TFLite Android app.

```
model_meta = _metadata_fb.ModelMetadataT()
model_meta.name = "SSD_Detector"
model_meta.description = (
    "Identify which of a known set of objects might be present and provide "
    "information about their positions within the given image or a video "
    "stream.")

# Creates input info.
input_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
input_meta.name = "image"
input_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties = _metadata_fb.ImagePropertiesT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties.colorSpace = (
    _metadata_fb.ColorSpaceType.RGB)
input_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.ImageProperties)
input_normalization = _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitT()
input_normalization.optionsType = (
    _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitOptions.NormalizationOptions)
input_normalization.options = _metadata_fb.NormalizationOptionsT()
input_normalization.options.mean = [127.5]
input_normalization.options.std = [127.5]
input_meta.processUnits = [input_normalization]
input_stats = _metadata_fb.StatsT()
input_stats.max = [255]
input_stats.min = [0]
input_meta.stats = input_stats

# Creates outputs info.
output_location_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
output_location_meta.name = "location"
output_location_meta.description = "The locations of the detected boxes."
output_location_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
output_location_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.BoundingBoxProperties)
output_location_meta.content.contentProperties = (
    _metadata_fb.BoundingBoxPropertiesT())
output_location_meta.content.contentProperties.index = [1, 0, 3, 2]
output_location_meta.content.contentProperties.type = (
    _metadata_fb.BoundingBoxType.BOUNDARIES)
output_location_meta.content.contentProperties.coordinateType = (
    _metadata_fb.CoordinateType.RATIO)
output_location_meta.content.range = _metadata_fb.ValueRangeT()
output_location_meta.content.range.min = 2
output_location_meta.content.range.max = 2

output_class_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
output_class_meta.name = "category"
output_class_meta.description = "The categories of the detected boxes."
output_class_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
output_class_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.FeatureProperties)
output_class_meta.content.contentProperties = (
    _metadata_fb.FeaturePropertiesT())
output_class_meta.content.range = _metadata_fb.ValueRangeT()
output_class_meta.content.range.min = 2
output_class_meta.content.range.max = 2
label_file = _metadata_fb.AssociatedFileT()
label_file.name = os.path.basename("label.txt")
label_file.description = "Label of objects that this model can recognize."
label_file.type = _metadata_fb.AssociatedFileType.TENSOR_VALUE_LABELS
output_class_meta.associatedFiles = [label_file]

output_score_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
output_score_meta.name = "score"
output_score_meta.description = "The scores of the detected boxes."
output_score_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
output_score_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.FeatureProperties)
output_score_meta.content.contentProperties = (
    _metadata_fb.FeaturePropertiesT())
output_score_meta.content.range = _metadata_fb.ValueRangeT()
output_score_meta.content.range.min = 2
output_score_meta.content.range.max = 2

output_number_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
output_number_meta.name = "number of detections"
output_number_meta.description = "The number of the detected boxes."
output_number_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
output_number_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.FeatureProperties)
output_number_meta.content.contentProperties = (
    _metadata_fb.FeaturePropertiesT())

# Creates subgraph info.
group = _metadata_fb.TensorGroupT()
group.name = "detection result"
group.tensorNames = [
    output_location_meta.name, output_class_meta.name,
    output_score_meta.name
]
subgraph = _metadata_fb.SubGraphMetadataT()
subgraph.inputTensorMetadata = [input_meta]
subgraph.outputTensorMetadata = [
    output_location_meta, output_class_meta, output_score_meta,
    output_number_meta
]
subgraph.outputTensorGroups = [group]
model_meta.subgraphMetadata = [subgraph]

b = flatbuffers.Builder(0)
b.Finish(
    model_meta.Pack(b),
    _metadata.MetadataPopulator.METADATA_FILE_IDENTIFIER)
self.metadata_buf = b.Output()
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much [Lu Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11031225/lu-wang). I made a gist based on your answer which actually generates .tflite model with metadata
https://gist.github.com/4PixelsDev/7400df5cd6f004c4d630c849660577d6

Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve my problem completely because, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64068862/1997514), looks like Tensorflow still doesn't support custom object detection model.

Comment: You can use the [TFLite Task library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/object_detector) to integrate custom object detection model. Let me know if you have problems using the Task library.

Comment: Hi Igor,  How does it goes? I tried as @Lu Wang suggestion. And read from your link regarding Tensorflow still doesn't support custom object detection model. Meaning it still cannot be solved?
Thanks

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030807/standard-tflite-object-detection-model-not-working-in-mlkit/64068862#64068862) that Igor pointed to says MLKit does not support custom object detection model, not TFLite. As I answered previously, you can use the TFLite Task library to integrate your custom object detection model.

Comment: Hey Lu Wang can you please share some resources if you have achieved getting the model integrated working . Because after going as per documentation of Task Library it says having a tflite metadata for float32 based models must have Normalization Options needed in the metadata, which can be seen here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d64c20eb62c5cfb9ff5936204afb8fb7c83cfc84/tensorflow/lite/experimental/support/metadata/metadata_schema.fbs#L295-L318 .  You have helped many  by sharing the snippet

Comment: Please refer to the [TFLite Object Detection Android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android). It contains two inference solutions, one using the [TFLite Task library](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java), the other using the TFLite Java API.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android#switch-between-inference-solutions-task-library-vs-tflite-interpreter) for instruction about how to switch between the two solutions.

Comment: error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes. Please help

Comment: Usually it's due to failing to pass in the correct TFLite model path. A common error is not to use quotation mark for the model name. Otherwise, please copy here your exact code snippet, and I can help to take a look.

Comment: Error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite_support_nightly (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite_support_nightly`