# Why I can't use AutoML VIsion TFLite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-cloud-automl

I've using Vision (GCP feature) to generated a custom object detection model and use it in my app (according to this library: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android)

But when I use it, it said:

```
Failed to initialize detector. Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0: got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1).
```

So I decided to use the TFLite task library. It looks fine when I took a picture in an empty black image. But when I try to take a picture with objects, it getting an error:
Expected locations tensor with dimensions [1,35,4] at index 0, found [1,40,4]

Is there any way to solve this? Or can you suggest any good way to make this work?

P.S. I've looked and try to solve with the information from [Standard TFlite object detection model not working in MLKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030807/standard-tflite-object-detection-model-not-working-in-mlkit)

Comment: Did you find any solution?